# NSMutableURLRequest "The request timed out" issue . .

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsmutableurlrequest, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I am trying to download data in my application by using the following code

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"my download url string"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60.f];

NSURLConnection * connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

[connection start];
```

but the problem is some times i am getting the following error

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x1d5be240 
{NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://dr282zn36sxxg.cloudfront.net/datastreams/f-
d%3Afc7f649e1e3ba58452f67e3fa1f66f69a15b96b3ea585c946e4fa854%2BEPUB%2BEPUB.1, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://dr282zn36sxxg.cloudfront.net/datastreams/f-
d%3Afc7f649e1e3ba58452f67e3fa1f66f69a15b96b3ea585c946e4fa854%2BEPUB%2BEPUB.1, 
NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x1e1975b0 "The request 
timed out."}
```

so , can anybody suggest me how to solve this . . .

Comment: what kind of data you're trying to download?

Comment: @iOSCoder Take a look at the error message ;)

Comment: @iOSCoder it's file with extension .epub

Comment: I just tried it in the simulator and it's definitely working

Comment: @riyaz It's a quite large file, so do you download it on Wifi or cellular?

Comment: Hmm ... For me it is definitely working. Is the page available in your country? I don't know if the unavailability of the page would produce a time out but honestly I have no other guess right now :(

Comment: @HAS i am able to download some data , even some times i can able to download complete file i.e around 20mb file. . .  but some times i am  getting this error during download. . .

Comment: have you tried using blocks?

Comment: @iOSCoder No . .i am not using blocks . .Is this error related to not using of blocks ?

Comment: @riyaz No it's not. The way you're dealing with it is correct!

Comment: @riyaz..no,just have a try with the below method...i strongly believe that its because of the spotty internet connection you are using...

Comment: @iOSCoder k i will try . . .

Comment: @iAppDeveloper Why would using AFNetworking solve hat issue? Regarding a specified timeoutInterval, both approaches MUST behave identical. Just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Increase the timeout interval like 150 secs .

Answer (score 1):

Try using GCDs abstraction called `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`:

**EXAMPLE**:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your_URL"];
NSURLRequest *myUrlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: myUrlRequest queue: queue completionHandler: ^ (NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{

    if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil)
        //doSomething With The data

    else if (error != nil && error.code == ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT)
        //time out error

    else if (error != nil)
        //download error
}];
```

**DOES IT MAKING ANY DIFFERENCE?**

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly states that the request has timed out - Get to a place you get better network speed or increase the request timeout, I see it as 60 now sometimes which may not be sufficient for image downloads.

Comment: It's not an image download ;)

Comment: In the current NSURLConnection implementation, a timeout occurs when there was "timeoutInterval" seconds *inactivity* on the connection. That is, even when the data gets in slowly, it should not timeout when you get at least one byte every "timeoutInterval" seconds (60 seconds, as specified).