# Request Timed out with Code=-1001_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102

Tags: ios, networking, timeout, nsurlsession

Sometimes network request from my app gets stuck, And I get the following error after a while,

```
failed with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1390937f0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://apis.xyz.xyz.com, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://apis.xyz.xyz.com, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
```

Any request I make after this, The same sent request is sent out and it fails with same error. So, no new request goes out.  This happens very rarely, but it does happen.

I am using `NSURLSessionDataTask:dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler` to make a network calls.

Comment: did you solve this problem?? Am getting this problem but can't find a solution can you help me out??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102 only with wifi of some ISPs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751432/kcfstreamerrorcodekey-2102-only-with-wifi-of-some-isps)

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: set `timeoutIntervalForRequest` in sessionConfig:

```
let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 180 // use a bigger number if needed
let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
    completionHandler(data, response, error)
})
```

Method 2: set `timeoutInterval` for request:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.timeoutInterval = 180 // use a bigger number if needed
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
    completionHandler(data, response, error)
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Increase the timeout interval like 150 secs .

Comment: I think you forgot to give the [Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18686791/4933696)!