# _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102 only with wifi of some ISPs

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, nsurlconnection

I use below code to send a file to the server:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[LIUtility sharedUtility].uploadConnectionURL,BR_SERVER_UPLOAD_ADDRESS_FILE];

self.request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[self.request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[self.request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

PKMultipartInputStream *body = [[PKMultipartInputStream alloc] init];

NSString *requestString =[self getRequestStringForRange:range andExtension:fileName];
NSData *requestData = [requestString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *jsonLengthString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04lu",(unsigned long)requestData.length];
NSData *jsonLengthData = [jsonLengthString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[body addPartWithName:@"jsonLength" data:jsonLengthData];
[body addPartWithName:@"json" data:requestData];
[body addPartWithName:@"separator" string:@"\r\n"];
[body addPartWithName:@"fileData" filename:fileName stream:dataStream streamLength:streamSize];

[self.request setHTTPBodyStream:body];
[self.request setTimeoutInterval:60];
NSString *contentType = LI_CONNECTION_CONTENTTYPE;
[self.request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:self.request delegate:self];
_responseData = [NSMutableData data];
[self.connection start];
```

The file is uploading with 3G/4G.The code also works when device is connected to wifi of some ADSL ISPs but in some other ISPs the code do not work and I get below error:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://example.net, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http:/example.net:80/au, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSUnderlyingError=0x16a40410 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://example.net, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://example.net, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}}

Does anyone have any idea about what is the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally solved my problem by adding `Content-Length` to the request.

When we do not add the `Content-Length` header to the request, `NSURLConnection` send it as a `chunked` request and it seems such problems is common with chunked requests.

Actually I do not found the root cause of the problem with this `chunked` request (I searched many subjects in web, reads many articles, talked with several other programmers but do not find any root cause, so I decide to use the other solution ) but I shared this solution for someone that can use non-chunked request in their business. As I know most usages of chunked requests are in real time streaming that we do not know the `Content-Length` so if you can add `Content-Length`, I suggest to use it for avoiding chunked problems like this.

Comment: This also worked for me. Not sure if this is relevant, but for reference: Xcode 7.2 using Swift, iPad with iOS 9.2.1. A newer Apple AirPort had the issue; an older one didn't.

Comment: @husein how to add content-length to get method. I am having same issue with GET method. Could you suggest on this issue. I am struggling from last 3 days

Comment: Yeah, no kidding, Content-Length fixed my issues as well. I was creating a streamed upload request using an InputStream and the call would never complete and would eventually time out. By manually adding the Content-Length header, the calls went through correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running an enterprise version of application, check with your server admin to see if your Cert is up to date and compatible with your firewall server. Mine isn't.

Answer (score -2):

I've just solved the issue ...

I hope this could help you if you don't find the solution on the Internet because this is a personal experience.

I've had configured all HTTP headers, all parameters and checked all programming on Objective-C, but I had forgotten to check server side, my architecture included 3 components: The app, REST server and a File server, file server was having networking issues with the domain so that's the reason because app was not working, after solving the issue it worked perfectly.